# Getting all checked items from a while loop and put them into database as true or false

Tags: php, mysql, select, checkbox

I am currently doing up a list of names that has signed up for a activity which is then needed to go through another selection process and to be put into the database. I have currently done the getting and displaying of names from the people that has signed up.

However, I am not too sure on the process of how I can get those checked which is being selected in the selection process.

This is currently the codes that I have done to get and display the names of the people who have signed up. Upon clicking submit, it would go to another page which would then process, get those checked and marked as 1 or true to the database (MySQL) or either set as 0 or false if it has not been checked.

```
<?php
                    if ($totalShortlist > 0) {
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $firstName = $row['first_name'];
                            $lastName = $row['last_name'];
                            ?>        

                            <form id="selectionProcess" action = "doShortlistProcess.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" method = "post">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="selectionProcess" id="selectionProcess" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/><?php echo $firstName; ?> <?php echo $lastName; ?></label>
                                </fieldset>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <input type="submit" class="btnSelect" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" name="shortlistCandidate" value="Submit Shortlisted Candidates"/>
                        </form>

                        <?php
                    }
                    // end for loop
                    else {
                        echo "No candidates to be shortlisted";
                    }
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
```

The $id as shown is the brought over from the list of categories on the previous page, which allows to get all the names in that categories to be displayed.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily solve your problem, but you open many <form> tags, and only close 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code places the form in the wrong place compared to the while loop. The action also doesn't need you to compose a query string. Better code (careful, I've also cut out some presentation):

```
if ($totalShortlist > 0) {
?>

    <form id="selectionProcess" action = "doShortlistProcess.php" method = "post">

    <fieldset>

<?php

    // use while loop to display a tick box for each item

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $firstName = $row['first_name'];
        $lastName = $row['last_name'];
?>                
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectionProcess" id="selectionProcess" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>
            <?php echo $firstName; ?> <?php echo $lastName; ?>
        </label>
    <?php
    } // end of while loop
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <?php
}    // end of shortlist > 0
```

I recommend you test this code using the GET method. It will show you what form the submission takes.
To process the result, you should use the list of responses, process it and turn it into one or more SQL statements.

An alternative would be to use an action for each checkbox, but then use ajax to a php page that would modify the status of single subscriber. The change would be made immediately as users click.